# Detect UIViewController change from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm trying to execute a function every time the app loads a new ViewController (transitioning to a different view). To avoid calling this function inside each ViewController (there are about 10 of them and more to be added), I'm hoping to do this in the AppDelegate by adding some sort of observer. Is this possible? Or can it somehow be done with the help of UIViewController extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can subclass UINavigationController and post notifications on events you are interested in:

```
class NotificationNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NavigationControllerWillPush"), object: nil)
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }

    override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NavigationControllerWillPop"), object: nil)
        return super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Then in your Application Delegate you can observe those notifications:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NavigationControllerWillPush"), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) {
            notification in
            // handle push
        }
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: "NavigationControllerWillPop"), object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) {
            notification in
            // handle pop
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget AppDelegate, observers or extensions, use [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)).

All your UIViewControllers should extend a MainViewController base class and you can put your logic in viewDidLoad method (or viewDidAppear) of base class.

Remember to call super class method when override.

Comment: Does that mean I would have to subclass each ViewController?

Comment: Yes you should. Code centralization is often the right way to avoid duplicated code and write more scalable programs